# Find all occurences of maximum value from a list of tuple?

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples such as:

```
list1=[(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,0),(5,0)]
```

I have found the maximum element using:

```
max_value = max(list1, key=itemgetter(1))
```

This outputs: `(1, 1)`

I want some thing like: `[(1,1),(2,1),(3,1)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Docs of [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

> If multiple items are maximal, the function returns the first one encountered. This is consistent with other sort-stability preserving tools such as sorted(iterable, key=keyfunc, reverse=True)[0] and heapq.nlargest(1, iterable, key=keyfunc).

You could select all those values that match the max_value using list comprehension

```
max_value = max(list1, key=itemgetter(1))[1]
ans = [y for y in list1 if y[1] == max_value]
```

```
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
```